# StickyBits Not Sticking

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm in the process of making a sticky navbar using Stickybits.  I see the classes being applied and position:sticky as well as my offset but the element just continues to scroll with the rest of the page anyway.

My question is, does it require that the parent element have a set height? From their documentation they say:

> Key Note: Stickybits expects and works best when the element that will become sticky is wrapped within a parent element that defines when the element starts being sticky and stops being sticky.

What exactly do they mean here? Are they saying that the parent element needs to have definitions with regard to height and positioning as well?

This is what I currently have:

```
$('.test').stickybits({ stickyBitStickyOffset: 82 });
$('.wsmainfull').stickybits({ stickyBitStickyOffset: 140 });
```

The .test element does not have a set height.

```
<div class="wsmobileheader-bottom test" style="position: sticky; top: 82px;"> ... </div>
```

The source HTML

```
<div class="wsmobileheader clearfix "> 
<div class="wsmobileheader-top">
<a id="wsnavtoggle" class="wsanimated-arrow"><span></span></a> <span class="smllogo">
<picture>
  <source data-srcset="assets/media/images/logo-header-horizontal.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source data-srcset="assets/media/images/logo-header-horizontal.png" type="image/png">
  <img src="assets/media/images/logo-header-horizontal.png" class="lazy" alt="logo"> </picture>
</span> <a href="tel:123456789" class="callusbtn"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> 
</div>
<div class="wsmobileheader-bottom test"> <a href="tel:123456789" class="btn cta-form"><i class="fas fa-phone-alt"></i> Tap To Call</a> </div>
```

Comment: Is the element that wraps the sticky bit element taller than the sticky bit element? Do you have some sample code maybe? That would make it easier to see what's happening.

Comment: I just updated to include that portion of the code.  I kind of think that something in my CSS may be overriding somewhere because a plain page with only the javascript works.  To answer your question, the element containing the child is NOT taller than it.

Comment: A sticky element only sticks within it's parent boundaries, meaning when the parent is scrolled out of view the sticky element will follow it as if it's not sticky, Also if the sticky element is the only child within it's container the stickiness won't be visible, it's  either must have a height or more children. modified [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/p63bcqto/) from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning) illustrating how it works

Comment: Okay now I understand. I appreciate the information.